# Pronunciation of final “e”

Tags: prononciation, paroles-de-chanson

I notice that sometimes in songs, a final *e* is pronounced. For instance in the song "elle était si jolie" by Alain Barrière, jolie is pronounced as /ʒo.li.e/ instead of /ʒo.li/. What is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En général ne prononce pas le « e » à la fin des mots.

Quand le « e » est ajouté comme marque du féminin après la consonne finale, il entraine la prononciation de cette consonne finale.

Dans ton exemple *jolie* est le féminin de *joli* et donc on prononce le *e* final.

On peut trouver ici un récapitulatif des lettres muettes : http://data.ruedesecoles.com/RueDesEcoles/Pdf/LitRef/littreref_37.pdf

On peut y voir que en fonction de la règion (dans sud de la France le e est prononcé), la prononciation peut changer.

Comment: Oui je prononce le e de jolie sinon comment différencier à l'oral le féminin du masculin ? Je ne pense pas que l'on dirait une joli fleur mais une jolie fleur. Même si on n'insiste pas sur le e comme dans la chanson, mais oui je le prononce.

Comment: Tu veux dire que le *i* est plus long ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_French#Phonology. Ça c'est bien possible. Je viens de Toulouse et je prononce les schwas, mais après une voyelle ça ne s'entends pas, au mieux ça l'allonge. Et on n'entend certainement pas un /øː/ ou un /eː/ comme dans la chanson. En Belgique c'est peut-être différent, mais Wikipédia laisse croire que non.

Comment: Oui on accentue plus la dernière consonne. Et en Belgique c'est comme en France ça dépend des règions et des des dialectes.

Answer (score 2):

Licence poétique.

Only to make the rhyme or fit the metric.

Answer (score 0):

*joli* ou *jolie* se prononcent de la même façon dans la vie courante, sauf accents régionaux particuliers ou intention particulière comme ici où c'est le jeu poético-musical de l'artiste qui déplace *l'accent tonique* sur le ***e*** final.